# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:Read error:ssl=0xb4000071bca8e448: Failure in SSL library,usually a protocol

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, ssl, android-volley

I'm using volley in my app and send request to my server but i got this error from my onErrorResponse volley:

```
Error: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Read error: ssl=0xb4000071bca8e448: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:10000438:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:587 0xb4000071bca09588:0x00000001)
```

I'm using device with android 11 and the request does not work what should i do?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have connected to wifi